# Python - How to use regex to find multiple words and extract them at the same time

Tags: python, regex

Using Regular Expression, I want to find all the match words in a sentence and extract the wanted part in the matches words at the same time.

I use the API "findall" from "re" module to find the match words and plus the brackets to extract the parts I want.

For example I have a string "0xQQ1A, 0xWW2B, 0xEE3C, 0xQQ4C".
I only want the remaining two words after "0xQQ" or "0xWW", which will result in a list ["1A", "2B, "4C"].

Here is my code:

```
import re

MyString = "0xQQ1A, 0xWW2B, 0xEE3C, 0xQQ4C"
MySearch = re.compile("0xQQ(\w{2})|0xWW(\w{2})")
MyList = MySearch.findall(MyString)

print MyList
```

So my expected result is ["1A", "2B, "4C"]. 
But the actual result is [('1A', ''), ('', '2B'), ('4C', '')]

I think I might have used the combination of "()" and "|" in the wrong way.
Thx for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Two different capturing groups will result in two items in the output (whatever matched each).

Instead, use a single capturing group and put your `|` (OR) earlier:

```
re.compile("0x(?:QQ|WW)(\w{2})")
```

(`(?:...)` is a *non-capturing* group that matches `...` - used to limit the effects of the `|` to only the QQ/WW split, without adding another capture to the output.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re

string = "0xQQ1A, 0xWW2B, 0xEE3C, 0xQQ4C"
pattern = re.compile(r"(0xQQ|0xWW)(\w{2})")

result = [match[2] for match in pattern.finditer(string)]
```

`result` will be:

```
['1A', '2B', '4C']
```